# Why when running yarn start, the css will changed?

Tags: angular, c#-4.0, yarn-v2

Recently, I had changed my css font size from 0.875rem to 1rem. However, after I run the command yarn start for testing, it had changed back the font size to 0.875rem. Any idea how to solve it, else it will be annoying to keep on changing the css every time.

**Original**

```
.btn-sm,
.btn-group-sm > .btn {
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
 font-size: 0.875rem;
  line-height: 1.5;
  border-radius: 0;
}
```

**Changes**

```
.btn-sm,
.btn-group-sm > .btn {
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
  font-size: 1rem;
  line-height: 1.5;
  border-radius: 0;
}
```

**After yarn start**

```
.btn-sm,
.btn-group-sm > .btn {
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
  font-size: 0.875rem;
  line-height: 1.5;
  border-radius: 0;
}
```

I had tried to clear the cache but it was still not working.
Appreciate that any expert can help on this..

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you modifying source or build css?

Comment: Im modifying the source css